# Why is a Java ternary "evaluated" before an or?

Tags: java

I have the following Java code snippet that is returning *false* when I would expect it to return *true*:

```
assertTrue(true || false ? false : false);
```

The statement has been dumbed down for the sake of this post (it was originally using string comparisons), and I know it can be simplified to not use the ternary operator, but basically I'm trying to figure out why Java evaluates it like this:

```
(true || false) ? false : false
```

rather than this:

```
true || (false ? false : false)
```

I would expect it to evaluate the *true* and exit. Does anyone know why it doesn't?

Comment: Operator precedence: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: This is why it's good to always use parenthesis.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "after an or" rather "before an or"?

Comment: I don't think my post was very clear. I'm just wondering why it doesn't return true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's what the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) says.  The relevant bits of the grammar are

```
Expression: 
     Expression1 [AssignmentOperator Expression1]

Expression1: 
     Expression2 [Expression1Rest]

Expression1Rest: 
     ? Expression : Expression1

Expression2:
     Expression3 [Expression2Rest]

Expression2Rest:
     { InfixOp Expression3 }
     instanceof Type


InfixOp: 
     || 
     &&
     // and many other operators
```

So to parse `A || B ? C : D`, the `? C : D` must be an `Expression1Rest`, and the right hand side of a `||` must be an `Expression3`, which does *not* include a ternary conditional expression (unless it is wrapped in parentheses - a parenthesized expression is always acceptable as an `Expression3`).  So we must parse the `A || B` as an `Expression3`, and thus the whole expression as if it were `(A || B) ? C : D`.

Comment: Thank you, the other answers were helpful, but this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Because of [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Logical AND and Logical OR have higher precedence than the ternary operator, so they act first.

Comment: Maybe my examples weren't clear. Wouldn't that imply that when the or evaluates, it would return true?

Comment: Basically, operator precedence acts like an implicit set of brackets. Because `||` is higher than `?:`, `true || false ? false : false` is equivalent to `(true || false) ? false : false`.

Answer (score 11):

Because `||` has higher precedence than `?:`. Here's a [table of operators in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Operators). The `||` has position 13 while `?:` is on position 14.

Answer (score 2):

So, there is something called "[operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)". It's the same concept as order-of-operations in mathematics. And just like in math `+` comes after `*`, in Java `?:` comes after `||`.

*Why* is this like this? Well, I think it helps to consider ternary as expanding to an `if` statement:

```
true || false? false: false;
// literally maps to
if(true || false) false; else true;
```

Comment: But note that this is not exclusive to Java.  Every programming language with infix operators has operator precedence.  Even maths has operator precedence.